# パンの作り方は何ですか。　OK?

Tags: grammar, questions

I am unsure if this is an acceptable way to say, "how do you make bread?"

確かに、

> パンの作りかたはどうしますか

という言い方や、

> どうやってパンをつくりますか

という言い方もあるとわかっていますが、「作り方」という言葉は名詞ですので

> パンの作り方は何ですか

と聞いてもいいでしょうか？

Comment: まず、「パンの作り方はどうしますか」は不自然です。「どうやってパンを作りますか」は少しましですが、何が主題歌を考えて「パンは（パンって）どうやって作るんですか」としたいところです。

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's acceptable, though one can see its meaning.

パンの作り方は何ですか is grammatically correct, saying "what is the way to make bread?"

But asking a way (やり方) by 何 is not natural. I feel 何 is asking something that can be answered using a noun (phrase). For パンの作り方, you need equipped sentences to describe it. So using どう is better.

Answer (score 2):

## English

I can understand what that means, but I have a feeling it's not entirely right.
 <sup>In the same way, I have a feeling that your first sentence is not entirely right, either.</sup> 
You should say:

> どうやってパンを作りますか.

## Japanese

意味は理解できます。ですが、その文には違和感があります。
<sup>「パンの作り方はどうしますか」も同じように違和感あり</sup>

> どうやってパンを作りますか？

と聞いたほうが自然です。

Answer (score 1):

Here is a casual expression off the top of my head:

パンって、どうやって作るの？
[How is bread made? or How do you make bread?]

If you are asking someone to teach you, you can say:

パンの作り方を教えてください。
[Please tell/teach me how to make bread.]

Comment: This doesn't really answer what OP is asking. The question is if the expression is acceptable or not (and how/why), and not about 'how to ask how?' thing.

Comment: @Yosh But he  is suggesting natural expressions.

Comment: I agree, thanks for the feedback! I'll be more careful next time.